# App tour only once to be displayed

Tags: android

Im asking on how to make the apptour on android to be seen only once when the user install the application in the device it should show 5 app tour fragments and plus i have 5 tour fragments each having its own class.

Comment: You can store simple boolean flag that would indicate that tour was presented to user already https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: I heard about sharred refference but i dont know how to implement them on my 5 fragment classes.... or simply how to implement it @VladimirLichonos